# How to create a Bot Channel Registration on Microsoft Azure? Blank error message when creating

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, azureportal

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/tutorial-voice-enable-your-bot-speech-sdk#create-a-channel-registration) to create a chatbot with a direct line speech channel. It's working fine until I'm at the part where I need to create a **bots channel registration**. I'm getting an empty error message, so I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help?

Here is the error message and the parameters that I've entered.
[image: Error]

Comment: Would you mind trying out the suggestions I gave here? https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1382#issuecomment-542876633

Comment: Are you still working on this?